# Can't find logical volume when booting imported disk images in Xen guest

Tags: filesystems, xen, lvm, boot

I've got a couple of drives I copied over using ddrescue to image files for booting under Xen. They contain an LVM volume group with a couple of volumes in it, which was originally split across two disks, one of which ended up failing but was successfully recovered. TL;DR the guest (Centos 5.8) can't find the logical volumes when I boot it up, and I need to figure out what my options are. Here's my xl-compatible.cfg:

```
# For centos import

name = 'placeholder'

# figure out pvhvm drivers
builder = 'hvm'

vcpus = 6
memory = '16384'

boot = 'c'

# according to xl.cfg man page it is 'guest specific' what this is
root = '/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00'

disk = [
      'file:/home/user/xenvms/placeholder/disk1.img,sda,rw',
      'file:/home/user/xenvms/placeholder/disk2.img,sda,rw',
      # copying over to new lvs instead of files didn't magically fix anything, consider this later
      #'phy:/dev/vg0/xen.placeholder.com-VolGroup00-disk1,sda,rw',
      #'phy:/dev/vg0/xen.placeholder.com-VolGroup00-disk2,sdb,rw',
   ]

vif = [ 'bridge=xenbr0' ]

#serial = 'pty'
vnc = 1
vnclisten = '0.0.0.0'
```

Here's what fdisk -l shows is in those images from the perspective of dom0, after making the devices available using losetup:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0007f805

Device       Boot  Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/loop0p1 *        63     208844     208782  102M 83 Linux
/dev/loop0p2      208845 3907024064 3906815220  1.8T 8e Linux LVM

Disk /dev/loop1: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000c421b

Device       Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/loop1p1 *       63 3907024064 3907024002  1.8T 8e Linux LVM
```

I am able to see the logical volumes using fdisk and lvdisplay if I boot the VM using system rescue CD:

[image: fdisk from sysrescuecd]
[image: lvdisplay from sysrescuecd]

And here's what happens when I boot it up. Does anyone know where I might start to get the booted guest OS to find the volume group?

[image: what it looks like on boot]

Comment: Not enough informaiton. What's guest distribution and version? Add rdshell (or rd.shell) to boot options. This should drop you into shell where you could try `lvs` to see if there are any errors in the output. `lsblk` to see what block devices are present. Run `vgscan` and see it that helps.

Comment: CentOs 5.8 for the guest here. rdshell or rd.shell is giving me the same screen you see there - Kernel boot parameters are the 2 entries for vmlinuz and kernel, and ro - the best I can give you is sysrescuecd, the rescue mode doesn't seem to want to work when i tried the centos install iso either so this is what works for me for now, but if that's necessary to get a closer distro environment's kind of look at it i can try harder to get it to recognize its own image as a cd

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the disk lines from sda to xvd was ultimately the solution:

```
      'tap:aio:/dev/vg0/xen.placeholder.com-VolGroup00-disk1,xvda,rw',
      'tap:aio:/dev/vg0/xen.placeholder.com-VolGroup00-disk2,xvdb,rw',
```